# Keep copy of original request in Servicestack Redis outq

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

I realise outq is used to see the last 100 or so responses for processed messages. However, the objects stored in outq only seem to have the response body, not the originating request, so it can be quite difficult to debug issues.

Is there an easy way to automatically include a copy of the originating inq message as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that works. Not sure if its optimal, but it seems to do the job.  When defining the handler I just create a new response object and insert original request into it.

```
mqService.RegisterHandler<MyRequest>(
    m => {
       var response = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MyService>().Post((MyRequest) m.Body);
       return new {result = response, request = m.Body};
    }
```